# ActiveDirectory - DirSync invalid or outdated cookie check

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, directoryservices

I'm working on an implementation which uses `System.DirectoryServices.Protocols` to establish communication with LDAP server (AD) and for querying via `SearchRequest`.

In addition to that, I'm using a `DirSyncRequestControl` to enable directory synchronization using DirSync cookie.

I've read about possibility to have invalid or outdated cookie which will cause exception (?) on the server, so that scenario must be handled.

However, I'm not able to find a proper way to handle that particular exception.

I couldn't find anything related to cookie invalidity inside [ResultCode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.protocols.resultcode(v=vs.110).aspx) enum nor specific exception/or exception message related to that issue.

I tried to look inside various exception structures from `DirectoryException`, `LdapException` and `DirectoryOperationException` but I didn't find anything useful (for this problem).

Please note, I **don't** have issues with DirSync search, it works as it should, I just want to make sure I'm handling properly all possible scenarios.

Comment: I've been working with DirSync control for the last 8 years and have never faced this issue. All you have to worry about is to connect to the same domain controller, while collecting changes. Otherwise, you may receive duplicated changes (already received somewhere in the past). To reproduce your issue you may try to corrupt cookie byte data (by truncating or modifying it manually) and then pass the cookie to a dc and see what happens

Comment: @oldovets thank you for your reply and suggestion, I've already tried to manually corrupt cookie, and as expected I got "LDAP protocol error" exception. However I found on a few different places statement about cookie corruption, so I wanted to investigate topic more thoroughly.

Comment: Could you please provide references to the places you mentioned that indicate cookie corruption problem? I'm wondering what are the details of the issue. My own search gave me only Java related problems

Comment: @oldovets Unfortunately those references are not from viable sources, I ran into few comments in various blog posts like [this one](https://dsablog.com/2012/07/17/caching-ad-info-using-directorysynchronization/) without further explanations.

Comment: Well, I believe that you have to contact Eric to understand, what he had in mind. I recalled one more trick: if you do not need AD objects themselves, while collecting initial cookie, just specify to collect instanceType attribute in attribute filter. The performance will go through the roof

Comment: @oldovets thanks for help and suggestions!